# 'Bijectively' apply list of functions to list of arguments

Tags: python, list, function, numpy, lambda

Say, I have some functions defined way back in the code; let us use two different PDF curves as an example:

```py
import numpy as np

# Gaussian 1
def fa(mu, sigsq, x):
    return ((np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigsq))**(-1) 
            * np.exp((-0.5 * (x - mu + 1)**2)/sigsq))

# Gaussian 2
def fb(nu, omsq,  x):
    return ((np.sqrt(2*np.pi*omsq))**(-1) 
            * np.exp(-(0.5 * (x - nu - 1)**2)/omsq))

...

fs = [fa, fb, ...]
```

Applying a list of functions with the same amount of arguments to some given ones is easy:

```py
fmap = lambda fns, *args: map(lambda fn: fn(*args), fns)

multipeak_gauss = lambda x: sum(list(fmap(fs, 0., 1., x)))
```

Now let each function have a unique, differently sized set of arguments:

```py
import numpy as np

# Gaussian
def fa(mu, sigsq, x):
    return ((np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigsq))**(-1) 
            * np.exp((-0.5 * (x - mu + 1)**2)/sigsq))

# Maxwell-Boltzmann
def fb(a, x):
    return (np.sqrt(2/np.pi) 
            * (x**2 / a**3) 
            * np.exp(-(x**2)/(2*a**2)))

...

fs  = [fa,           fb,       ...]
ars = [[0., .1, 1.], [1., 1.], ...]
```

The list of lists of arguments can just as well be a list of tuples or anything of that sort. How does one pass each set of arguments to each function one-to-one without having to rewrite all functions to accept a list?

My best guess thus far:

```py
specmap = lambda fns, *args: [fn(arg) for fn, arg in zip(fns, *args)]
```

This code runs into the obvious problem that it passes a list on to a function that expects just plain arguments. Intuition tells me I can somehow 'unwrap' each list in the list of lists further with something like

```py
specmap = lambda fns, *args: [fn(ar for ar in arg) for fn, arg in zip(fns, *args)]
```

though the above code is clearly dysfunctional and I do not know how exactly it could be done.

Comment: `[fn(*args) for fn, args in zip(fnlist, argslist)]`.  Keep the args tuples together until passed to fn,

Comment: @hpaulj bingo! I don't know why I didn't try that combination before, it worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @hpaulj please don't use comments to write the answer, but just write a short answer.

Comment: @Grismar, I wrote that comment on my phone.  My answers are usually longer and include a copy-n-paste of working code.

Comment: That explains the brevity, but it would still have been better as an answer, since it's now a matter of waiting until someone else writes that answer (and gets the credit for no reason) or util @AndriiKozytskyi decides to answer their own question and accept the answer. I appreciate your input and you were absolutely correct, I'm just pointing out that the question now remains unanswered and your contribution gets more or less lost as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined  by @hpaulj in the comments, the solution was to 'open' the particular list of arguments inside the function:

```py
specmap = lambda fns, args: [fn(*arg) for fn, arg in zip(fns, args)]
```

while keeping the input list of sets as a list, not as a *list object.